# A more readable way of working with EF.Property

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm working a lot with temporal tables in SQL Servers for checking if entities recently changed.
For that I need to extract the `PeriodStart` and `PeriodEnd` properties over and over.
E.g. I have a lot of code like this:

```cs
queryable
    .Filter(e => EF.Property<DateTime>(e, "PeriodStart") > lastSyncTimestamp
        && EF.Property<DateTime>(e, "PeriodEnd") < utcNow)
```

This long syntax with `EF.Property` ruins the readablility, especially if you have multiple checks in a row.

I've tried writing extension methods for the properties `.Filter(e => e.PeriodStart() > lastSyncTimestamp)`, but EF Core cannot longer understand the query with them.

Is there a good way of making working with properties easier and more readable?

---

The best way so far that I was able to come up with is to make a new type, and then do some logic with it later. But that's still quite cumbersome.

```cs
queryable
    .Select(e => new { Id = e.Id, PeriodStart = EF.Property<DateTime>(e, "PeriodStart"), PeriodEnd = EF.Property<DateTime>(e, "PeriodEnd") })
    .Filter(e => e.PeriodStart > lastSyncTimestamp && e.PeriodEnd < utcNow)
```

Answer (score 3):

EF Core has a set of operators in the format of extension methods upon `DbSet<T>` in order to execute queries upon the temporal date-time properties.

From the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-6.0/whatsnew#querying-historical-data)

> - `TemporalAsOf`: Returns rows that were active (current) at the given UTC time. This is a single row from the history table for a given primary key.
> - `TemporalAll`: Returns all rows in the historical data. This is typically many rows from the history table for a given primary key.
> - `TemporalFromTo`: Returns all rows that were active between two given UTC times. This may be many rows from the history table for a given primary key.
> - `TemporalBetween`: The same as TemporalFromTo, except that rows are included that became active on the upper boundary.
> - `TemporalContainedIn`: Returns all rows that started being active and ended being active between two given UTC times. This may be many rows from the history table for a given primary key.

See the source code at [GitHub](https://github.com/dotnet/efcore/blob/767bc93c6e6fca19868f486c7df8f4235bcf53cd/src/EFCore.SqlServer/Extensions/SqlServerDbSetExtensions.cs#L126).

---

An example

```
var from = DateTime.Now;
var to = from.AddDays(6);
var products = dbContext.Products.TemporalBetween(from, to);
```